# getting month from given date php

Tags: php, date, timestamp

given this code to retrieve the **date from** and **date to**:

```
<dl>
        <dt><label for="calendar">Date From:</label></dt>
     <dd><input type="text" name="timestamp" id="calendar1" class="calendarFocus" size="32" maxlength="128" /></dd>
    </dl>

   <dl>
        <dt><label for="calendar">Date To:</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="timestamp1" id="calendar1" class="calendarFocus" size="32" maxlength="128" /></dd>
    </dl>
```

how can I get only the month?

**this is the Output format of the date above in timestamp: 13/09/2011 10:05... thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`date('M', strtotime( $timestamp ));`

Swap `M` with any of the following:

- `F`  -- A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March. *(**January** through **December**)*
- `m`  -- Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros    *(**01** through **12**)*
- `M`  -- A short textual representation of a month, three letters *(**Jan** through **Dec**)*
- `n`  -- Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros *(**1** through **12**)*
- `t`  -- Number of days in the given month    *(**28** through **31**)*

Answer (score 0):

```
 $date_from = $_POST['timestamp'];
 $month_from = substr($date_from,strpos($date_from,'/'),2);
 $date_to = $_POST['timestamp1'];
 $month_to = substr($date_to,strpos($date_to,'/'),2);
```